# Can't locate the database files in postgresql ubuntu

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, ubuntu

I can't seem to locate the main db files of my postgresql database in ubuntu. I listed out the directory in psql by command SHOW_DIRECTORY and it gave me the location "/var/lib/postgresql/10/main".
But when I go to that directory, I can't see the db files that I have. I can only see files like pg_dynshmen, pg_notify, pg_stat etc and folders - base and global. I have 4 databases which include 2 templates but none of them are here.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub-directory `base` contains databases and `global` global objects (users etc).

But... do NOT go fiddling with any of this stuff directly. Unless you really know what you are doing and are recovering a crashed database all you are likely to do is destroy your data.

You would typically be backing up your databases with `pg_dump` or `pg_restore` or via `pg_basebackup` and WAL shipping if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Oh, so I should do this 'pg_dump -U postgres -O db -f db.sql ' as the db owner, from the destination directory ?

Comment: Yes. `-Fc` is a typical flag to use too. That will produce a "custom" format dump, which is roughly speaking a zipped dump that `pg_restore` can extract pieces from as well as restore the entire database.